# autoplay video in slider

Tags: jquery, video, slider, autoplay

I am using the cycle2 plugin, and i have a video gallery and what i am after is when the current slide is shown, autoplay the video.

He does have a similar plugin for this but it looks like it's only for youtube whereas i am using the video html tag with fallbacks:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/video.php

Obviously i cant can't add autoplay to the videos as they all play at once and not sure how to handle this. Is there a way around from his api url: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/ or will i have to create a function from scratch that when a certain slider is selected, play/stop.

I am using his hashing example that is on his website as well.

If anyone has any ideas where to start or the right direction to a solution i would be grateful as i've looked at this for hours!

Here is a link to an example of how the video is integrated into the cycle2 slider:

http://jsfiddle.net/8dcWv/

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" controls="controls">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="" />
  <source type="video/webm" src="" />
  <source type="video/ogg" src="" />
  <object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="">
  <param name="movie" value="" />
  <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&file=" />
  </object>
</video>
```

plugin url: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/video.php

This url could be helpful to trigger first slide: https://github.com/malsup/cycle2/issues/25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should work.

```
//Triggered after the slideshow has completed transitioning to the next slide.
$( '#mySlideshow' ).on( 'cycle-after', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    $('video', incomingSlideEl)[0].play();
});

//Triggered just prior to a transition to a new slide.
$( '#mySlideshow' ).on( 'cycle-before', function(event, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl, incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag) {
    $('video', outgoingSlideEl)[0].pause();
});
```

Comment: This is 99% there! Only issue i have is that the first slide isn't autoplaying, only when i go to another thumbnail and then back as the cycle-before/cycle-after event is triggering it (if that makes sense). How would i get the first video to play then behave like the rest once i start moving slides? This is fantastic help by the way!

Comment: Add this at the beginning before the listeners
`$('cycle-slideshow div')[0].play();`

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, tried that before your answer and it just breaks the slider and the autoplaying for the rest. Strange as we are only asking for a div with a video in to play.. not sure if the cycle plugin likes it?

Comment: Try changing the class from `.cycle-slideshow` to something else and then initiating it manually like this `$( '.mySlideshows' ).cycle();` before trying to do the last suggestion and adding the listeners.

Comment: nope, no luck, even tried adding an id to the first video slide but still doesn't autoplay- this is very strange!! Also tried: $("#video-one").get[0].play();

Comment: How about `$( '#mySlideshow' ).on( 'cycle-post-initialize' function(){$('#mySlideshow video')[0].play()});`

Comment: No still no luck, no replies on his issue forum as well, oh dear!

Comment: Perhaps you can make a working jsfiddle.net and let us play with the code to see if we can get what you want.

Comment: @user2212564 The following code will autoplay the video in the first slide on page load **and** after each transition (so you don't need the `cycle-after` hook, only the `cycle-before` one): `$( '#mySlideshow' ).on( 'cycle-update-view', function(event, optionHash, slideOptionsHash, currentSlideEl) { $('video', currentSlideEl)[0].play(); });`